# Can somebody identify this tea?

Tags: tea

I was eating at my local Denny's and when you ask for tea, they give you some hot water and two of the below tea bags. On the menu it says "Hot Tea / Herbal Tea" but the tea bags only say Lipton and don't say what kind. I am hoping to identify what type of Lipton tea this is. I know the inside has a number on the bottom which didn't help me in Google.

[image: Top View]
[image: Back View]
[image: Inside View]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webadress "www.ufs.com" and the text "This unit not labeled for retail sale" tell you that this is the tea mix Unilever delivers to restaurants, senior homes etc. The rainforest alliance logo is used for coffee and black tea, so it's not herbal tea. (That the menu lists both, only means both are available, typically for the same price; without qualifier a server will always assume "tea" = "*black* tea".)

As this paper wrapper does not give details, you could ask your server (tip generously...!) for package details or check the [ufs website](https://www.unileverfoodsolutions.us/product-catalog/lipton/tea-beverages.html?refine=[slugified_brand_name_facet~lipton][slugified_category_name_facet~tea-beverages]). My gut feeling is that it's the [standard Lipton black tea](http://www.liptontea.com/product/detail/141444/black-tea-cup-size):

[image]

... or at least a very similar blend.

Comment: Stephie - While this is clearly a foodservice item, not being labeled for retail sale does not mean that a product can't be sold at retail. It means that the individual unit is not for retail sale, so you would have to buy it in a package of "X" number of units. This same wording is often found on retail items that contain more than one unit as the units are not meant to be sold individually.

Comment: I finally was able to strike a conversation with a server who brought the entire box out to show me. It was Lipton 100% Natural America's Favorite Tea (Serve Hot or Iced) 100 Tea Bags as you show above. I noticed that the tea didn't taste the same at first because I believe that my tea water is actually TOO hot. Once it cooled down a little bit it started tasting the same.

Answer (score 2):

Lipton brands it's tea as "Orange Pekoe", which this essentially means it's black tea from India or Sri Lanka. Black tea has caffeine in it, Lipton averages at about 40mg per cup, which is pretty moderate compared to coffee, but is not caffeine free like some herbal teas.

Comment: From Google Images, when I type in Lipton Black Tea Bags, the packaging is exactly the same when other variants have different labels. Thank you for pointing out black tea as I thought I Googled that before.